# Deep Learning for sequences

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, hidden-markov-model, artificial-intelligence, deep-belief-networks

I want to use deep learning techniques to perform better inference tasks than Hidden Markov Models (which is a shallow model)? I was wondering what is the state-of-the art deep learning model to replace Hidden Markov Models (HMM)? The set-up is semi-supervised. The training data X(t),Y(t) is a time series, with significant temporal correlations. Also, there is a huge amount of unlabelled data, i.e., simply X(t) and no Y(t). After reading many papers, I narrowed down on the following model -> Conditionally Restricted Boltzmann Machines (Ilya Sustkever MS thesis) and use Deep Belief Networks for unsupervised pretraining (or use variational autoencoders for pretraining). I am very new to the field, and was wondering if these techniques are outdated.

Comment: the state-of-the-art currently for this task is undoubtedly Recurrent Neural Networks (LSTMs and GRUs)

Comment: @antoine the "recurrent" part in RNN is basically a compact way to store past history by allowing for "cycles" in the ANN graph, and I am well aware of it. Though I know that training the RNNs is tricky, there has been recent progress in training RNNs (Ilya Sustkever's Phd thesis), I would like to start with something more basic.

Comment: Unsupervised pre-training is no longer state of the art -- advances in regularization methods (dropout, max norm) and transfer functions (ReLU and variants) make that unnecessary. Antoine is correct that RNNs **are** the state of the art in deep learning for sequences -- to the point that RNNs and deep learning for sequences are, effectively, synonyms.

Comment: @rahuls88 RNNs indeed have been around for a long time, but the LSTMs and GRUs architectures are much more recent and considered cutting edge, as far as I know. And within the context of your question (how to improve on HMMs), LSTMs/GRUs implement tricks to preserve their memory over time while taking into account the new observations, so they can capture dependence between 2 elements in the series for a much longer time than HMMs (which make the Markov assumption). Check out the RNN tutorial by Denny Britz (from Google Brain), it is really good

Comment: @antoine looks good....will try RNNs also

Comment: @Sycorax@Antoine is unsupervised pretraining really out of fashion? The problem I am facing is that there is only unsupervised data, and its a sequential data, i.e., think of something like a HMM model (only that it need not be restricted to Markovian dependencies). How do I use gradient descent on this? Should I label the data according to labels generated by the HMM (Baum Welch , Viterbi algorithm), and then use SGD on this labelled data? Or should I use Unsupervised pretraining first, and then use labels generated by Baum Welch to train using SGD?

Comment: @rahuls88 I'm not familiar with the other techniques you mention, but still within the context of deep learning, unsupervised pre-training is quite common. In supervised NLP applications for instance, people will often use as the initial word vectors the output of word2vec (which is unsupervised) applied to a very large corpus. For instance, the Google News word vectors are frequently used and are publicly available. And I know that in computer vision, there are also some pre-trained feature vectors for images.

Comment: @rahuls88 BTW: using the output of some pre-trained model as a starting point is often called *transfer learning* in this context. And in CV, people often start with some of the weight matrices of a network trained on the ImageNet database (14 million images) for classification, even if their downstream task is different. Check out: https://adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks-Part-2/ (Transfer leaning section)

Comment: @Antoine thanks, looks good, I will try unsupervised pretraining also....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the various RNNs mentioned in the comments, another type of layer that can be used when both the input and the output is a sequence is the following CRF-style layer (gave state-of-the-art results for named-entity recognition as in the paper mentioned below, as well as [sequential short-text classification](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.05251)). I have only used it for fully supervised tasks though.

https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.03475 (*De-identification of Patient Notes with Recurrent Neural Networks*) uses a neural network with a "label sequence optimization layer" as the top layer to do some sequence tagging, which could be seen as a "deep learning" equivalent to CRF.

See *Section 2.2.4 Label sequence optimization layer*:

> The label sequence optimization layer takes the sequence of
>   probability vectors $\mathbf{a}_{1:n}$ from the label prediction layer
>   as input, and outputs a sequence of labels $y_{1:n}$, where $y_{i}$ is
>   the label assigned to the token $x_{i}$.
>
> The simplest strategy to select the label $y_{i}$ would be to choose
>   the label that has the highest probability in $\mathbf{a}_{i}$, i.e.
>   $y_{i}=\text{argmax}_{k}{\mathbf{a}_{i}[k]}$. However, this greedy approach
>   fails to take into account the dependencies between subsequent labels.
>   For example, it may be more likely to have a token with the PHI type
>   STATE followed by a token with the PHI type ZIP than any other PHI
>   type. Even though the label prediction layer has the capacity to
>   capture such dependencies to a certain degree, it may be preferable to
>   allow the model to directly learn these dependencies in the last layer
>   of the model.
>
> One way to model such dependencies is to incorporate a matrix $T$ that
>   contains the transition probabilities between two subsequent labels.
>   $T[i,j]$ is the probability that a token with label $i$ is followed by
>   a token with the label $j$. The score of a label sequence $y_{1:n}$ is
>   defined as the sum of the probabilities of individual labels and the
>   transition probabilities: $$ s(y_{1:n}) = { \sum_{i=1}^{n}
> > \mathbf{a}_{i}[y_{i}]+  \sum_{i=2}^{n} T [y_{i-1},y_{i}} ]. $$ These
>   scores can be turned into probabilities of the label sequences by
>   taking a softmax function over all possible label sequences.  During
>   the training phase, the objective is to maximize the log probability
>   of the gold label sequence. In the testing phase, given an input
>   sequence of tokens, the corresponding sequence of predicted labels is
>   chosen as the one that maximizes the score.

The network:

[image]

Code: https://github.com/Franck-Dernoncourt/NeuroNER

Comment: @Frank thanks for the reference...looks good, I will try it out